# im new to react-native i want to implement a timer where i would be able to start and pause a timer after a certain period of time

Tags: react-native

i want to implement a countdown timer function when user click on a button  it start and also stop but it not working when i do that  but i have checked through the function but i'm not see what wrong with it . i hope someone can put me on why the function is not working while is being clicked

```
const minutesToMill = (min) => min * 1000 * 60;
const formatTime = (time) => (time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time);

export const Countdown = ({ 
  minutes = 20,
 isPaused,
  }) => {
    const interval = React.useRef(null)
   const countDown =()=>{
     setMillis((time)=>{
       if(time===0){
         return time
       }
       const timeLeft = time -1000
       return timeLeft;
     })
   }
 
  const [millis, setMillis] = useState(minutesToMill(minutes));

  const minute = Math.floor(millis / 1000 / 60) % 60;
  const second = Math.floor(millis / 1000) % 60;


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPaused) {
      return;
    }
    interval.current = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, [isPaused]);

  return (
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      {formatTime(minute)} : {formatTime(second)}
    </Text>
  );
};


export const Timer = ({focusSubject})=>{
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.countdown}>
    <Countdown  isPaused={!isStarted}  />
    </View>
    
    <View style={{paddingTop:spacing.xxl}}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Focusing on </Text>
     <Text style={styles.task}>{focusSubject} </Text> 
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
    {
      isStarted ? (  <RoundedButton  title="start" onPress={()=>setIsStarted(false)}/>) : (
         <RoundedButton  title="pause" onPress={()=>console.log(setIsStarted(true))}/>
      )
    }
```

Comment: I changed the `RoundeButton` with a `Pressable` and your code works fine. The problem is probably in the `RoundedButton` component

Comment: Can you please paste the code … I’m a new to react-naive

Comment: i  have changed it but it still given me issue  import {Pressable, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Pressable>
     <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
      <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </Pressable>
   
  );
};

Answer (score 0):

In your `RoundedButton` you're **not** passing the `onPress` prop to the actual `Pressable` component. You can fix your issue by doing so.

```js
import { Pressable, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  onPress, // destructure it from the props
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Pressable onPress={onPress}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
        <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```